# Android Dual Drawers - Navigation with Navigation View and Navigation Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation

Developing a heritage tracking application !

I need to have a Navigation Drawer on the left and another Navigation Drawer with Checkbox.

The Left side Drawer is generated using the Android Studio and the right side code I have implemented.

Only one of them is getting displayed. How do i get the Navigation View on the right and Fragment Drawer on the left.

---

XML below

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">



<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="org.janastu.dualnavigation.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `app_bar_main` is an `AppBarLayout` or `Toolbar`, then I would assume that:

1. You don't want it filling up the entire screen.
2. You don't want it being treated as the main content of the `DrawerLayout`.

On that note, try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Your Toolbar or Appbar. I've included what it should look like here
         to point out that layout_height SHOULD NOT BE match_parent.-->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!--Main Content-->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <!-- Left side drawer layout -->
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

        <!-- Right side drawer layout. Important to note that fragment_navigation_drawer
             should have a background colour. -->   
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            android:name="org.janastu.dualnavigation.FragmentDrawer"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```